# retieve data from mysql and display in form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a radio box and 2 drop down menus which when submitted save to mysql. The radio box is either yes or no and the 2 dropdowns where created in html. It is currently fully working and saves all the data.

What I now wish to do is when a user logs back in, it will show what they have previously selected (if they have).

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require_once("config.php"); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header('Location: login.php'); 
   exit; 
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT attendance1 FROM user WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if(($row[0] == "Yes") || ($row[0] == "No")){
        header("Location: errorsubmit.html");
        exit;
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){         
     $sql = "UPDATE user SET attendance1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance1']) . "' WHERE username = '" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

   $sql = "UPDATE user SET colour1= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['colour1']) . "' WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

   $sql = "UPDATE user SET shade1= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shade1']) . "' WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

   header("Location: thanks.html", true, 303);
}
?>
```

FORM:

```
<form>
         <input name="attendance1" type="radio" id="Yes" value="Yes" checked="checked"/>Yes
         <br />
<input name="attendance1" type="radio" id="No" value="No" />No
       </h3></td>
       <td>
              <select name="colour1" id="colour1" >
           <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
           <option>Red</option>
           <option>White</option>
           <option>Green</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td><h3>
                 <select name="shade1" id="shade1" >
           <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
           <option>light</option>
           <option>heavy</option>
         </select>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td><label>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" />
       </label></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below:

you need to fetch values from database and match them with select box values to show them selected.

```
<select name="shade1" id="shade1" >
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option value="light" <?php if($val=='light') echo 'selected'; ?>>light</option>
  <option value="heavy"<?php if($val=='heavy') echo 'selected'; ?>>heavy</option>
</select>
```

Here `$val` is variable having value retrieved from database.

while adding you should have :

```
<option value="light" >light</option>
<option value="heavy">heavy</option>
```

Comment: thanks I tried this the values from the drop down do not appear to what they are in the database. It is still 'please select' even though ive removed the selected from 'please select'

Comment: seems you need to update again for a user becaue you have to value atttribute in your select box option values. Please put them and update again

Comment: I have reselected and submitted. When I Log back in 'please select' is showing for each drop down still :s

Comment: im not sure what you mean by 'while adding you should have :'

Comment: Please check your query or are u getting values from database. do banchmarking

Comment: It all looks correct. The result submit but when I log back in it does not show the results i Just submitted

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check if the value in the database has the value of the option field, and if so you echo a "selected='true'" to your option tag. Like

```
<option <?php if($row["column_name"] == "light") echo "selected=\"true\""; ?>>light</option>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work although i know it should it just comes up as please select when i log back in